# Smart Keyboard for 10.5" iPad Pro broken

Tags: ipad, hardware, repair, smart-keyboard

I purchased a Smart Keyboard for my 10.5" iPad Pro in March 2018. Around December 2018/January 2019, it started failing: after putting it into the typing position, the software keyboard would stay on screen, as if the Smart Keyboard wasn't there. I tried some simple troubleshooting steps, which didn't fix the issue. Since it was still under warranty, I got Apple to send me a new one. The new one worked without a hitch... until now.

Again, the same symptom is happening: the software keyboard stays on screen after setting it into the typing position. Since all Apple stores are closed due to the current pandemic, and anyway the product is no longer under warranty, I don't expect Apple to fix it.

I tried cleaning the contacts on the iPad's Smart Connector as well as the corresponding pins on the Smart Keyboard using isopropyl alcohol, but it made no difference.

I'm fairly sure this is an issue of mechanical fatigue on the internal cabling, arising from the repeated action of opening and closing the keyboard, but I'd be most thrilled (although not really hopeful) to find any solutions that didn't involve replacing the keyboard.

I'm looking for any other troubleshooting tips, as well as reports of similar cases, and any information about possible repair programs in effect (searching the web, I discovered that the previous version of the Smart Keyboard, for the 9.7" iPad Pro, has or at least had a repair program valid for 3 years from the date of purchase, but was unable to find anything about the 10.5" iPad Pro). Any tales of trying to replace the Smart Keyboard at an Apple Store after the warranty has expired, despite the lack of an official repair program, are also welcome.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re looking for here as you have the answer to your issue - the Smart Keyboard has failed. All of Apple's repair programs are listed in one place so if you’re not seeing it, it doesn’t exist. Please understand, the is a **question and answer** site and not a forum like Reddit. .

Comment: Although all signs point to hardware failure, perhaps someone knows of a software solution. Perhaps someone knows a trick (I recall reading something about realigning the magnets the first time it failed). Perhaps someone was lucky enough to get it exchanged at an Apple Store — there’s only two of them in my country, and I don’t live in either city, so it’d be expensive to travel to one unless there’s a good chance of getting it replaced. Finally, maybe it’ll serve as a warning to people that this keyboard is a piece of junk and they should think long and hard about getting one.

Comment: Software doesn’t fix hardware failures and again, you’re already familiar with “tricks” so did you attempt it?  As far as anecdotal stories of other people’s experiences, they’re one offs.  Each will be different and there’s no magic phrasing that bypasses warranty repair policy.  Again, you have to try and plead your case, but your best bet is to not buy it again and get a Logitech or other high quality 3rd party product.

Comment: I have the same problem here on the larger (12 in.) model. Sometimes I get a message popup "This accessory is not supported by this device.". Apparently this is a common problem: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7678022. Obnoxious.